# @+id/ Which special characters are allowed?

Tags: java, android, xml

This is a pretty basic question but I couldn't find a clear answer to this.
Most learning resources say, you can't use special characters in a View ID, but underscore `(_)`, dot `(.)` and dollar sign `($)` work. Are there other special characters that are allowed?

Answer (score 3):

No, Android doesn't provide any other special character for defining `View` Id.
In fact these rules are not defined by Android language, but by `XML`.

Comment: So . _ $ are the only ones? I didnt miss any?

Comment: Yes! 
But usually developers only use underscore (`_`). So stick to it, unless your whole team uses the other two.

Answer (score 0):

It's a standard way to use a variable id/ name, Developers should use underscore to specify the name clearly *eg. city_name*. Otherwise you can use camelCase eg. *userName* (2nd word 1st letter is capital).